# Robotlegs AS3-Signals Dispatch signal from ItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, robotlegs

I have a mediated view with a DataGroup with a custom ItemRenderer. I want when I click a button in the ItemRenderer to dispatch a signal and handle it in my mediator? How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your item renderer dispatch an event that bubbles, then on your DataGroup add a listener for that event (in your mediator).

Comment: I've made a custom event and I've managed to get it with AddViewListener(). How can I do the same with a signal?

Comment: A signal from your item renderer, or the DataGroup?

Comment: So I am guessing these ideas didn't help? http://knowledge.robotlegs.org/discussions/questions/313-dispatch-signal-from-itemrenderer

Comment: I actually would not use Signals in an item renderer and instead use events. I tend to treat item renderers as black box UI elements. While it may be possible, I am not sure the benefit would be worth the possible overhead of setting it up in this case.